# Initial Value exercise

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I am trying to find the predicted weight of a person after t days of being on a diet and exercise program. An 180-pound man eats 2500 calories of food and burns 17.5 calories per pound of weight. The model I came up with for the resulting change in weight is this one

> dw/dt = (2500/3500) - (17.5/3500)w, w(0) = 180.

How long will it take for the person to lose 20 pounds? What happens to the man's weight if they continue this program indefinitely?

Comment: Looks like an easy first order ordinary differential equation.  You can integrate this in one step to get a general solution and plug in your initial condition.  What's the problem?

Comment: Stephen Wolfram knows how to solve it: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27(t)+%3D+c1+-+c2*y(t)

Comment: I'm not sure that your model is a good one, but that's another matter.  What is your explanation for the 2500/3500 constant?  That makes no sense to me.

Comment: Try better luck at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: is this even a mathematica question?

Comment: I got a solution.  Why wouldn't it be a Mathematica question?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the 3500 figure: ["Common dieting wisdom says that we’ll lose one pound for every 3,500 calories we burn. Is that true?"](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/03/05/3500-calories-one-pound-fat-calorie-burn_n_2806578.html) - Huffington Post

Calculation using Mathematica

```
eqn = b'[t] == (2500 - 17.5 b[t])/3500;

sol = DSolve[{eqn, b[0] == 180}, b[t], t];

b[t_] := Evaluate[b[t] /. sol]

Quiet@Solve[b[t] == 160, t]
```

> {{t -> 154.638}}

```
Limit[b[t], t -> Infinity]
```

> {142.857}

20 pounds are lost after 154.638 days.  Continued indefinitely weight plateaus at 142.857 pounds.

```
Plot[{b[t], 160}, {t, 0, 1000}, AxesLabel -> {"Days", "Pounds"}]
```

[image]

You can find details of the hand-calculation here: [A mathematical diet model](http://users.sch.gr/toumasis/Amathdietmodel.pdf).

E.g.

```
db/dt = (2500 - 17.5 b[t])/3500

∴ db/dt + 0.005 b[t] = 2500/3500

∴ E^( 0.005 t) b[t] = (2500 E^( 0.005 t))/(3500*0.005) + k

k = b[0] - 2500/(3500*0.005)

∴ b[t] = 2500/(3500*0.005) + (180 - 2500/(3500*0.005)) E^( -0.005 t)
```

Check

```
when t = 154.638

b[t] = 2500/(3500*0.005) + (180 - 2500/(3500*0.005)) E^( -0.005 t) = 160
```